# Ploting function for specified combination of parameters

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Please help to plot given function:

```
g[a_, b_] := (0.5*a)/b^3;
```

I am trying with the code given below but we found all combinations of `f(t,a1,b1), f(t,a2,b1), ....` and so on. I want to plot `f` as function of `t`, like `f(t,a1,b1), f(t,a2,b2), ...., f(t,a3,b3)`.

```
f[t_, a_, b_] := 2*Exp[-t/g[a, b]]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[t, a, b], {a, .010, .030, .010}, {b, .001,.003, .001}],
{t, 0, .5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: yes,code is working. total 9 permutation possible for our given a and b range .  I  want to plot  only f(t,a1,b1) f(t,a2,b2) and f(t,a3,b3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g[a_, b_] := (0.5*a)/b^3
f[t_, a_, b_] := 2*Exp[-t/g[a, b]]
```

I'd go with constructing only the parameters you want to plot:

```
param = Transpose@{Range[.010, .030, .010], Range[.001, .003, .001]}
```

> {{0.01, 0.001}, {0.02, 0.002}, {0.03, 0.003}}

and then feeding them to the function `f`:

```
func = f[t, ##] & @@@ param
```

> {2 E^(-2.*10^-7 t), 2 E^(-8.*10^-7 t), 2 E^(-1.8*10^-6 t)}

to produce only the list of functions that are to be plotted:

```
Plot[Evaluate@func, {t, 0, .5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@ It is working. Now I can can also make table like : Transpose@{Table[a, {a, .001, .003, .001}], 
  Table[a, {a, .001, .003, .001}]} which gives  same  outputs  (*{{0.001`,0.001`},{0.002`,0.002`},{0.003`,0.003`}}*)

Comment: Sure, but the syntax of `Range` requires less typing than `Table`, and does the same in all instances I can imagine that might occur in such setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g[a_, b_] := (0.5*a)/b^3;
f[a_, b_] := 2*Exp[-t/g[a, b]];
lst = MapThread[f, {{.010, .030, .010}, {.001, .003, .001}}];
Plot[lst, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

giving

[image]

There are two instead of three lines since two of them are identical. Indeed:

```
lst

(*  {2 E^(-2.*10^-7 t), 2 E^(-1.8*10^-6 t), 2 E^(-2.*10^-7 t)}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: You copied the iterators from `Table`, not the actual values to `MapThread`.

Comment: @ corey979 You are right. However, the idea stays true.